# How to insert as many numbers as were mentioned before using raw_input?

Tags: python, python-2.7, raw-input

I want the user of my program to provide a number and then the user must input that number of numbers.

**My input collection code**

```
inp1 = int(raw_input("Insert number: ")) 
inp2 = raw_input("Insert your numbers: ")
```

---

**Example:**

If the user enters `3` at `Insert number:` then they have to input three numbers (with spaces between them) at `Insert your numbers:`.

How do I limit the number of values in the second response to the amount specified in the first response?

---

I assume, we should use a list to work with.

```
my_list = inp2.split()
```

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: You can certainly split using space `inp2.split(' ')`

Comment: Are you asking how to limit the number of values in second response to the amount acquired in the first response?

Comment: @whitebeard Yes, that's pretty much what I want.

Comment: Do **not** follow the advice from  @Oluwafemi Sule. You run the risk of getting undesired outcomes if you follow that advice. Read the split() documentation to understand why `inp2.split()` is superior to `inp2.split(' ')` for this use case. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Comment: You are right if there are consecutive space runs. You probably want to link to the https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `len` function to get the length of the list, then test if it is correct:

```
inp1 = int(raw_input("Insert number: "))
inp2 = raw_input("Insert your numbers: ").split()
while len(inp2) != inp1:
    print "Invalid input"
    inp2 = raw_input("Insert your numbers: ").split()
```

Another approach would be to get each input on a new line seperately, with a loop:

```
inp1 = int(raw_input("Insert number: "))
inp2 = []
for i in range(inp1):
    inp2.append(raw_input("Enter input " + str(i) + ": "))
```

This way, there are no invalid inputs; the user has to enter the right amount of numbers. However, it isn't exactly what your question asked.

Comment: The second approach makes the program more user friendly!  Nice!